# C# - Basic question: What is '?'?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I'm wondering what `?` means in C# ?
I'm seeing things like: `DateTime?` or `int?`. I suppose this is specific to C# 4.0?
I can't look for it in Google because I don't know the name of this thing.
The problem is I'm using DateTime and I have a lot of cast errors (from `DateTime` to `DateTime?`).

Thank you

Comment: It's not new; been around since .NET 2.0.

Comment: Not to be confused with the traditional C if-then-else operator, x<0 ? "-" : "+"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's a shorthand for writing `Nullable<int>` or `Nullable<DateTime>`. [Nullables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) are used with [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34yytbws%28VS.71%29.aspx) that cannot be null (they always have a value).

It is not specific to C#4 by the way.

You can only assign an `int?` to an `int` if it has a value, so your code would have to do things like:

```
int? n = 1;
int i = n ?? default(int); //or whatever makes sense
```

Also note that a `Nullable` has two properties, `HasValue` and `Value` that you can use test if a value has been set and to get the actual value.

Comment: @Brian Gideon, you are totally right, I just wanted to illustrate that a Nullable has those two properties.

Comment: @klausbyskov: It's fine to point out those properties, but you've given them in an example where they are a poor choice - maybe you could make a note of them separately and use `??` for the assignment to `int`.

Comment: @280Z28 good point. I have done that.

Comment: What if I wanted to make a class of mine Nullable? How can I do it? Is there any interface I need to implement?

Comment: A class instance is already able to be null.  Nullable is used for structs, which cannot natively be null.

Comment: @Amokrane you may want to read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34yytbws%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: I'd add that `myNullableInt != null` is generally more readable than `myNullableInt.HasValue`, which is why they added it. Both compile to the same thing, but `!= null` is a more universally recognised check for non-null variables.

Comment: You can also use `n.GetValueOrDefault()` instead of `n ?? default(int)`

Answer (score 12):

It means it's a [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

It allows you to assign a null value to value types such as int and DateTime. It's very helpful with things like optional fields in a database.

Answer (score 5):

It designates [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

> I suppose this is C# specific to C#
>   4.0?

It has been in C# since 2.0

Answer (score 5):

The `?` is a nullable value type.

You can use the `??` operator to mix it with value types:

```
const int DefaultValue = -1;

// get a result that may be an integer, or may be null
int? myval = GetOptionalIdFromDB();

// the value after ?? is used if myval is null
int nonNullable = myval ?? DefaultValue;
```

The nullable type can be compared to null, so the above is shorthand for:

```
if( myval != null ) {
    nonNullable = myval.Value;
} else {
    nonNullable = DefaultValue;
}
```

But I prefer `??`

Answer (score 1):

A gotcha to look out for: [edit: apparently this only happens sometimes]

```
// nullable type properties may not initialize as null
private int? foo; // foo = 0

// to be certain, tell them to be null
private int? foo = null;
```

Comment: That's not been my experience: Can you post a full repro with a main method and everything? Like this:

    static class Program
    {
        private static int? i;
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }

Comment: Actually, you're right... when I do a straight up test in Snippet Compiler, it does initialize to null.  When I've written code in a page code-behind, accessing properties from another public sealed class, I've seen them initialize as their value type defaults.  I'll have to dig deeper to find out when/why that happens.

-1 from myself!

Answer (score 1):

It is a shorthand way of declaring an implementation of the generic class `Nullable<T>`, where T is a non-nullable value type.

So

```
int? i = null;
```

is the same as

```
Nullable<int> i = null;
```

As mentioned above `Nullable<T>` exposes the HasValue property so you can check if `i` has a value before working on it.

Interesting to note: If you cast `Nullable<int> i = 3;` to an object, you can cast back to an int or a `Nullable<int>` because it had a value before boxing. If, however you cast `Nullable<int> i = null;` to an object you will get a NullReferenceException when casting back to an int but you can cast back to a `Nullable<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, after the name of a type it means the nullable type.

? is also used in the condition operator.

```
int max = x > y ? x : y
```

This is equivalent to:

```
int max;
if( x > y )
{
  max = x;
}
else
{
  max = y;
}
```