# What is the benefit of using int16? instead of int16 in a .net variable declaration?

Tags: .net, variables, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - Basic question: What is '?' ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699373/c-basic-question-what-is)

What is the benefit of using int16? Instead of using int16 in .net variable declaration ?

```
dim i as int16?
dim i as int16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question mark indicates Nullable Types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: thnx thnx thnx ur URL coverd the need

Answer (score 5):

It allows you to have a "null" value.  Generic example:

```
public int MyFunction(int? x)
{
    int m = 99;

    if(x == null)
        m = 0;
    else
        m /= x.Value;

    return m;
}
```

Otherwise, if try to pass a null value to MyFunction, the compiler will return an error.

Comment: +1 @Gats - good catch :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676078/which-is-preferred-nullable-hasvalue-or-nullable-null

Comment: I wouldn't call me clever.. I wrote an answer about why you'd use Int16 over Int32 before I realised I'd missed the point :D:D

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really about "benefit" - it is about *representing something subtly different*; an `Int16?` is really just shorthand for `Nullable<Int16>`, which means it is capable of representing a null/empty state in addition to the regular `Int16` range. But the downside is that it takes more space. So if space efficiency is your aim (which mainly only makes sense in an array, etc) you may want to think carefully.

Comment: thnx u r wright i had to use anthor word but ......