# int? maxResults what does the ? means in this statement

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - Basic question: What is ‘?’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699373/c-sharp-basic-question-what-is)

I have found this statement in a function arguments.

```
public static SyndicationFeed GetDataFeed(...... int? maxResults)
```

what does that means?

Comment: [`Nullable<T>` Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx#Y0)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

int? means it's a nullable int, so not only integer values are allowed but also the null-value.

Answer (score 8):

Its a [Nullable Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx#Y0), `Nullable<T>`. As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

DataType `int` is basically a value type and cannot hold null value, but by using Nullable Type you can actually store null in it.

```
maxResults = null; // no syntax error
```

You can declare the `Nullable Types` by using two syntax:

```
int? maxResults;
```

OR

```
Nullable<int> maxResults;
```

Answer (score 2):

`?` means nullable.  It means the type can contain a value or be null.

```
int? num = null; // assign null to the variable num
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's a shortcut for `Nullable<int>` - This means that `maxResults` can be assigned null.

Comment: i think you mean Nullable<int>, cause there is no interface for nullables

Answer (score 2):

Represents a `int type that can be assigned null.`

Answer (score 1):

Typically an int cannot have a *null* value, however using the '?' prefix allows it to be [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
int? myNullableInt = null; //Compiles OK
int myNonNullableInt = null; //Compiler output - Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type
int myNonNullableInt = 0; //Compiles OK
```

In the context of your question/code I can only assume that it is responsible for returning **SyndicationFeed** results based on the value of **?maxResults**, however as its nullable this value could be null.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign `null` to any **value type**,that includes `integer`.You will get an exception

```
int someValue;
someValue=null;//wrong and will not work
```

But when you make it nullable,you can assign null.
To make a ValueType Nullable,you will have to follow your valuetype keyword with the symbol  **?**

```
<type>? someVariable;

int? someValue;
someValue=null;//assigns null and no issues.
```

Now you wont get an exception and you can assign null.